# How to get non-expired wordpress jwt token from postman to set on flutter ecommerce config file?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, jwt

I have e-commerce flutter application, backend is Wordpress, API communication, so every-time get product info from Wordpress will need bearer token that I it store on config file,  i request once from Postman API 
`url/index.php/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/`

But after few day when initiate loading main page, it will failed, and i will need request again token and copy paste into flutter config file and only can work again. please advice.

Any parameter able to put into request and get non expiring token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jwt.io
used this link to check exp(expired date), the edit date by using
https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php
, after that update [your-256-bit-secret] by checking wordpress 
JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY value and paste into your-256-bit-secret, 
run and copy paste token into config or local storage